# How to use C Libraries for Arduino code

Tags: c++, c, ide

I have a code in Visual studio that I want to implement in Arduino. But
there is a problem. Many libraries usable in Visual Studio aren't usable
in the Arduino IDE. How can I use them in my Arduino code? To be
precise, the libraries I want to use are

```c++
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <queue>
#include <string>
#include <math.h>
#include <ctime>
```

I know I have `<iostream>` available in Arduino. `<math.h>` is also
available I think along with the `<string>` library. The main problem is
to how to use `#include<queue>` and its functions such as
`priority_queue()` and other functions of iosteam like `.pop()`? Any
help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Weird, I can remember using the same ATMega328P with another compiler, where it did work.
Though you can check if an external library fits your needs: http://playground.arduino.cc/Code/QueueList

But I would understand if you prefer a solution rather than a work-around?

Comment: The Arduino doesn't have an operating system, so therefore doesn't have a C standard library.

Comment: @mypal125: The Arduino _does_ have a standard C library ([avr-libc](http://www.nongnu.org/avr-libc/) for the AVR based boards). What it lacks is the C++ STL, but see Nick Gammon's answer on how to add it.

Comment: @EdgarBonet: TIL!

Answer (score 4):

Some of the libraries you mention (iomanip, iostream, queue, string) are part of the STL - Standard Template Library. Whilst it does not ship with the IDE download, you can install it yourself. See [The Standard Template Library (STL) for AVR with C++ streams](http://andybrown.me.uk/wk/2011/01/15/the-standard-template-library-stl-for-avr-with-c-streams/) - a port to the Arduino by Andy Brown.

I have some [implementation notes here](http://www.gammon.com.au/forum/?id=11119).

Be aware that a lot of Arduinos don't have much RAM, so you need to use libraries like this with caution.

Library download: [AVR standard template library, version 1.1.1](http://andybrown.me.uk/wk/files/avr-stl-1.1.1.zip) - 197.29 kB